# Multiple consumer Rabbitmq through multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, multiprocessing, pika

I am trying to create multiple consumer for a RabbitMQ client.
I am using PIKA and trying to do with multiprocessing.
It seems connecting but not being able to sustain the loop.
Can you please help.
The part of the code should also take care the writer option through the call back.

it should start the loop and should consume always

```html
import multiprocessing
import time
import pika
# this is the writer part
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print (" [x] %r received %r" % (multiprocessing.current_process(), body,))
    time.sleep(body.count('.'))
    # print " [x] Done"
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

def consume():
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(userid, password)
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(url, port, '/', credentials)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        parameters=parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='queuename', durable=True)
    channel.basic_consume('queuename',callback)
    print (' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
    channel.start_consuming()

userid = "user"
password = "pwd"
url = "localhost"
port = 5672

if __name__ == "__main__":

    workers = 5
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=workers)
    for i in range(0, workers):
        pool.apply_async(consume)

    #Stay alive
    try:
        while True:
```

Comment: I tried reproducing your problem. Everything's working fine for me. Deployment environments are `OS`: `MacOS`, `RabbitMQ`: `3.7.10`, `python`: `3.6.3`

Output:
`[*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C
 [x] <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)> received b'Message: 0'
 [x] <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)> received b'Message: 1'
 [x] <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)> received b'Message: 2'
 [x] <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)> received b'Message: 3'
 [x] <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)> received b'Message: 4'`

Comment: Yes but it is not consuming steadily

Comment: What do you mean by steadily?

Comment: I mean it is just consuming 5 messages and after that the channels are closed and the consumers are disconnected. Thanks for looking in to it

Comment: Are you trying to run any long-running jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing any exception handling in your sub-processes, so my guess is that exceptions are being thrown that you don't expect. [This code](https://gist.github.com/lukebakken/c81a28c523354d9bdea774b758e2402a) works fine in my environment, using Pika 1.1.0 and Python 3.7.3.

Before I checked for exceptions in `body.count()` a `TypeError` would be thrown because `body` was not a `str` in that case.

Please note that I'm using the correct method to wait for sub-processes, according to [these docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join).